# mysql special characters utf-8

Tags: mysql, utf-8, dump

I have the everlasting problem with german special characters:

I got a mysqldump from a mysql database.
When I open it in the shell with vim, most of the special characters are displayed correctly, like äü...

But ß is broken.
I check the encoding with

```
$file -bi mysqldump.sql
```

and it says

```
$text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

I have MySql 5.0.51a with UTF-8 Unicode.
When I import the mysqldump.sql all special characters are broken. I tried

```
mysql -u databaseuser -p database < mysqldump.sql
mysql -u databaseuser -p database < mysqldump.sql --default-character-set=utf8
mysql -u databaseuser -p database --default-character-set=utf8 < mysqldump.sql
```

Nothing works. 
Unfortunately I don't have access to the original database. So the dump is given.

The special characters are a neverending nightmare....
Any help very welcome,

cheers Joerg

Comment: have you tried to add a "SET names 'utf8'" as first line in the dump bevor importing ?

Comment: When I write SET names 'utf-8' I get an error. But I discovered this in the first line: latin1:EXTINFO So I have Latin1?

Comment: Ah, that's it, I found the line /*!40101 SET NAMES 'latin1' */; right under the table info part and changed it to /*!40101 SET NAMES 'utf8' */; Seems to work!!! Thanks!